# Como pegar pontos X e Y em uma Div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando criar o seguinte quadro
[image: Div]

E quero traçar uma linha entre cada uma delas, que fique dessa maneira
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito que é pegando o eixo X e Y, como faço isso?

Comment: Você pode brincar com o Canvas.

Comment: O ponto inferior esquerdo é `(div3.pageX, div3.pageY + div3.height)`; o superior direito é `(div2.pageX + div2.width, div2.pageY)`.

Comment: Não é bem o que você quer, mas [eis uma solução CSS3](http://jsfiddle.net/aaccioly/v64R4/). Baseada [nessa resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19848543/664577) do SOen

Comment: Que tal isso aqui, baseado no que o Anthony colocou, é o que quer? http://jsfiddle.net/s4bNw/

Comment: Pode ser, mas será que ficaria melhor com div ou dar uma olhada em canvas como o @dxhj comentou

Comment: As duas soluções são aceitáveis, julgo eu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preparei uma solução mais flexível para você, baseada nos comentários e sem a necessidade de qualquer JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="elements">
    <div class="negate"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
    <div class="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#elements {
  width: 420px;
  height: 220px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.element {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.negate {
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to top left,
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 0%, 
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) calc(50% - 3px), 
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 1) 50%, 
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) calc(50% + 3px), 
      rgba(255, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Para brincar e testar, preparei [este jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chiefGui/tnpLk/). Para um visual mais próximo do por você apresentado, veja o [update 1](http://jsfiddle.net/chiefGui/tnpLk/1/).

Comment: css3, Nice! Front-end op